# How to use Jenkins.getInstance().getItem in jelly script for email-ext plugin

Tags: jenkins, jelly, email-ext

I need this code in my jelly script for email-ext:

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("Job_name").getBuilds()
```

Is it possible to use in script without changing plugin code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get to the Hudson instance by using jelly:core tags:

```
<j:invokeStatic className="hudson.model.Hudson" method="getInstance" var="hudsonInstance"/>
```

From here, just keep using jelly:invoke, etc., to get to the instance methods that you need.   Here you will find the jelly:core taglib docs:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/tags.html